# HTML href links does not work after i added javascript to navigation component

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, href

I have a simple main navigation menu created with html and css. When I added some javascript to handle the collapsing and toggling for the button for the mobile menu, every link on the page stops working.

I based the navigation off of this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQjzzq

```js
(function() {

  // Definition of caller element
  var getTriggerElement = function(el) {
    var isCollapse = el.getAttribute('data-collapse');
    if (isCollapse !== null) {
      return el;
    } else {
      var isParentCollapse = el.parentNode.getAttribute('data-collapse');
      return (isParentCollapse !== null) ? el.parentNode : undefined;
    }
  };

  // A handler for click on toggle button
  var collapseClickHandler = function(event) {
    var triggerEl = getTriggerElement(event.target);
    // If trigger element does not exist
    if (triggerEl === undefined) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

    // If the target element exists
    var targetEl = document.querySelector(triggerEl.getAttribute('data-target'));
    if (targetEl) {
      triggerEl.classList.toggle('-active');
      targetEl.classList.toggle('-on');
    }
  };

  // Delegated event
  document.addEventListener('click', collapseClickHandler, false);

})(document, window);
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" id="navigation" class="list">
          <a href="http://sitename.se/site/index.html" class="item -link">Hem</a>
          <a href="http://sitename.se/site/vart-boende.html" class="item -link">Vårt Boende</a>
          <a href="http://sitename.se/site/om-vald.html" class="item -link">Om Kvinnovåld</a>
          <a href="http://sitename.se/site/lankar.html" class="item -link">Länkar</a>
          <a href="http://sitename.se/site/engagera-dig.html" class="item -link">Engagera Dig</a>
          <a href="http://sitename.se/site/english.html" class="item -link">English</a>
          <a href="http://sitename.se/site/kontakt.html" class="item -link">Kontakt</a>
        </nav>

        <!-- Button to toggle the display menu  -->
        <button data-collapse data-target="#navigation" class="toggle">
          <!-- Hamburger icon -->
          <span class="icon"></span>
        </button>
```

Comment: You're setting a global click handler on the whole document.  When a clicked element doesn't have "data-collapse", and neither does its parent, you preventDefault.  So, when someone clicks a link (doesnt have data-collapse nor does its parent), preventDefault executes which cancels the click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the links are not working because they are having their default behavior prevented on line 19 on the JavaScript. If I'm understanding the situation correctly, you only want the event listener to apply to the collapsible menu, so I'd suggest altering the code to something like this:

```
 // Delegated event
document.getElementsByClassName('toggle')[0].addEventListener('click', collapseClickHandler, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault() is the culprit, since following links when the user clicks is the "default" behavior of a link.

Try this on any web page and then try to click a link:

```
const f = e => e.preventDefault()
document.addEventListener('click', f, false)
```

You probably want to make sure the element clicked is what you think it is and then and only then preventDefault().